# Alguna solución, estoy haciendo un deploy Django con Amazon Web Service

Tags: django, webservice, nginx, aws, amazon

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Django y lo quiero montar en mi servidor de Amazon Web Service ocupando nginx/gunicorn.

Quisiera que me pudieran ayudar ya que he al parecer no es capaz de procesar mi petición de entrada mi proyecto que estoy montando en Amazon Web Services.

Tengo mi settings.py así:

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ip_addresses()
```

Ya intenté con `ALLOWED _HOST = ['DNS O IP' DE MI SERVIDOR]`.

En la parte de `Sites-available` tengo esta parte:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ec2-54-197-38-157.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location /static/ {
      root /home/ubuntu/EC2;
  }
  location / {
      include proxy_params;
      proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/EC2/EC2/.sock;
  }
}
```

Por lo cual el error es que nunca entra al proyecto, me manda directo a `error 502 Bad Gateway`.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ec2-54-197-38-157.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location /static/ {
      root /home/ubuntu/EC2/;
      index index.html index.php;
  }
  location / {
      include proxy_params;
      proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/EC2/EC2/.sock;
  }
}
```

Al parecer te faltaba cerrar EC2/ y colocar esto:

```
index index.html index.php;
```

que es la página de inicio.

Comment: Me causa duda que tú última línea de código hablé sobre extensión .php cuando la pregunta es sobre Django